# Google sheets macro to paste row at first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I am trying to record a macro to copy row number 2 and append it (values only) to the first empty row in my sheet.
- I was only able to paste "over" the last row with data but I can't get the macro to move to the first empty row, any help appreciated.

code:

```
function test21() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunk101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```